# How to configure pusher correctly in React native?

Tags: react-native, pusher

**Problem:**

In my web application, I have connected to channels and sent messages successfully without any issues. This is how I have organized my pusher subscription codes like this.

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js')

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: my_key,
  cluster: 'ap2',
  forceTLS: true,
  encrypted: true,
  authorizer: (channel, options) => {
    return {
      authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
        httpClient.post('/user/chatauth', {
          "socket_id": socketId,
          "channel_name": channel.name
        })
          .then(response => {
            callback(false, response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            callback(true, error);
          });
      }
    };
  },
})
```

And here I am providing how I have added the message listening part.

```
window.Echo.private('chat.' + userSelector.role + userSelector.user_id)
    .listen('.newMessage', ({ chat, user_data }) => {
        console.log(user_data)
        //other logics to update states
    });
```

After that now I am creating the same logic with react native mobile app. This is how I have organized my subscription part in react native in a useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userSelector) {
        const pusher = new Pusher("my_key", {
            "cluster": "ap2",
            "encrypted": true,
            "channelAuthorization": {
                endpoint: "myURL/api/user/chatauth",
            }
        })
        
        const channel1 = pusher.subscribe('chat.' + userSelector.role + userSelector.user_id)
        
        // You can bind more channels here like this
        // const channel2 = pusher.subscribe('channel_name2')
        channel1.bind('.newMessage', function (data) {
            console.log(data, "data")
        })
        

        return (() => {
            pusher.unsubscribe('chat.' + userSelector.role + userSelector.user_id)
        })
    }

}, [userSelector, isFocused])
```

After I send a message from the website but it is never received in the mobile app. But when I try it with two browsers its working like charm. But not with a mobile app.

I tried a lot to find out the issue but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to make this work? Thank you